# Resizeable angular-material drawer with collapsing content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a resizeable mat-drawer that changes/collapses its content when it gets resized to a certain min-width. To turn the mat-drawer into a resizeble element, I've used [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element) and it seems to work quite nicely already.

The only problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to collapse the content while dragging the resize bar, it's only changed after the mouse-up event is triggered. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a reproducible example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kepsi2?file=src/app/sidenav-drawer-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `[enableGhostResize]="true"` and use the `(resizing)` event instead of the `(resizingEnd)`

```
  <mat-drawer class="custom-drawer" mode="side" opened mwlResizable [ngStyle]="resizeStyle" [validateResize]="resizeValidate" [resizeEdges]="{right: true}" (resizing)="onResizeEnd($event)">
```

https://angular-kepsi2-bvnviu.stackblitz.io/